# Java regular expression. Alphabetic, with spaces and apostrophe (')

Tags: java, regex

what is the pattern to validate the following regular expression in java.
string with only letters, spaces and apostrophes (')

I know that for letters is this `("^[a-zA-Z]+$")`
For spaces is this `("\\s)`
I don't know what apostrophe is.

But most of all i just want a single expression. Not 3 individual ones.

Comment: An apostrophe. All can go inside the character class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own class with the characters that you need to match, like this:

```
Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z\\s']+");
```

Comment: Instead of a-zA-Z I'd recommend \p{IsAlphabetic} for Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

there is no single class that could match something so specific, but you can build your own from the existing ones

```
(\p{Alpha}|\s|')*
```

matches any number of characters, spaces or apostrophes, in any order.

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Yikes. Don't use alternation when a character class can do the same.

Comment: Please also note that \p{Alpha} only matches ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]*$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Tester String");
System.out.println(m.matches());// true
Matcher m2 = p.matcher("Tester String 123");
System.out.println(m2.matches());// false
```

This will accept only alphabets.